# Issue with Animation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to complete the animation in JavaScript, but all is working perfectly fine, except the last stage, I've typed the code for the inner box to move left, still, it goes up, out of the box. Please help by pointing out whats going wrong. The problem lies with the function moveleftagain();, the last function. But I've clearly instructed it to go left, still it goes left. Please do help.

```js
var ctr = 0;
var ctr2 = 0;
var inner = document.getElementById('in');
var t = setInterval(moveright, 10);

function moveright() {
  if (ctr == 150) {
    clearInterval(t);
  } else {
    ctr += 1;
    inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
  }
}
var t2 = setInterval(movedown, 10);

function movedown() {
  if (ctr == 150) {
    if (ctr2 == 150) {
      clearInterval(t2);
    } else {
      ctr2 += 1;
      inner.style.top = ctr2 + "px";
    }
  }
}
var t3 = setInterval(moveleft, 10);

function moveleft() {
  if (ctr2 == 150) {
    if (ctr == 0) {
      clearInterval(t3);
    } else {
      ctr -= 1;
      inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
    }
  }
}
var t4 = setInterval(moveup, 10);
var check = false;
var checkdiag = false;

function moveup() {
  if (ctr == 0) {
    if (ctr2 == 0) {
      clearInterval(t4);
      check = true;
    } else {
      ctr2 -= 1;
      inner.style.top = ctr2 + "px";
    }
  }
}
var t5 = setInterval(movediagonalright, 10);

function movediagonalright() {
  if (check == true) {
    if (ctr == 150) {
      clearInterval(t5);
      checkdiag = true;
    } else {
      ctr += 1;
      ctr2 += 1;
      inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
      inner.style.top = ctr2 + "px";
    }
  }
}
var t6 = setInterval(moveleft2, 10);
var checkdiagleft = false;

function moveleft2() {
  if (checkdiag == true) {
    if (ctr == 0) {
      clearInterval(t6);
      checkdiagleft = true;
    } else {
      ctr -= 1;
      inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
    }
  }
}

var t7 = setInterval(movediagonalrightup, 10);
var checkdiagright = false;

function movediagonalrightup() {
  if (checkdiagleft == true) {
    if (ctr == 150) {
      clearInterval(t5);
      checkdiagright = true;
    } else {
      ctr += 1;
      ctr2 -= 1;
      inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
      inner.style.top = ctr2 + "px";
    }
  }
}
var t7 = setInterval(moveleftagain, 10);

function moveleftagain() {
  if (checkdiagright == true) {
    if (ctr == 0) {
      clearInterval(t7);
    } else {
      ctr -= 1;
      inner.style.left = ctr + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #out {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      background: #FF0000;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #in {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background: #000000;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="out">
    <div id="in"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ever heard of CSS animation? It is more clear and simpler. https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation2

Comment: @RandyCasburn No harm in pointing someone to better optimised solutions, tbh.

Comment: @RandyCasburn It's a comment. I would understand this kind of harshness for an answer that goes completely off track, but commenting 'have you tried that?' does not.

Comment: `var t7` was declared twice and the wrong interval was cleared in `movediagonalrightup()`

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML yes, i also work with CSS animations, but this was the part of project I was completing, just to hone my logic.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to harm anyone by just simply suggesting another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movediagonalrightup` keeps running and increments `ctr` by 1 while you try to decrement it in `moveleftagain`

you probably want to `clearInterval(t7);` in `movediagonalrightup`.
also this `var t7 = setInterval(moveleftagain, 10);` should be `var t8 = setInterval(moveleftagain, 10);`
you have two `t7`

here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1h4amvkb/) so you can play with

Comment: oh, i got the error of my ways, basically what i did was, since the functionality of moving left was same, what i did was copy the function from above that I created for moving left, but then i forgot to change the new Timers for intervals, and since most of the code looked the same I simply could not find the error, even when it was right infront of you, i didn't even look at your fiddle, all i saw was the line in your answer "movediagonalrightup keeps running" and I understood what the error was, thanks.